# Can't listen port 80 inside my jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins, port

I have a jenkins container running on port 8080 to make some tests. Inside this container, I have a nginx container running on port 80 and I want to test http request.
[image: docker ps]

But inside my jenkins container, the port 80 is not listened. I tried to expose the port 80 while creating the jenkins container via docker-compose but still not working. I can't use firewalld and iptables inside the container.

[image: curl on container]

Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: You are using 127.0.0.1:80 from Jenkin container. To connect to nginx , you should use container-name of nginx container (it will act as hostname of nginx container) rather than 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: UPDATE : You're right, I can now curl to nginx container with the name. It wasn't working previously because my two containers wasn't on the same network. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

there is a catch that hit me when using non-root users and low ports:

When a Docker container runs as a non-root user, the process running inside the container has limited permissions and cannot bind to privileged ports (i.e., ports below 1024) like port 80. However, you can still expose port 80 on the container by using a non-privileged port on the host machine and mapping it to port 80 inside the container.

For example, if you want to expose port 80 of the container to port 8080 on the host machine, you can use the following command:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 --user nonrootuser your-image
```

This command maps port 8080 on the host machine to port 80 inside the container, and specifies that the container should run as the nonrootuser user.

Note that the container app must be configured to listen on port 80 inside the container, even though it will be accessed via a non-privileged port on the host machine.